# Paypal - Mass Pay blocked?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using sandobx to test my masspay code. I make everything like in docs: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_MassPayUsingAPI#id101DEJ0100A but i get error:
User not allowed
The user is not allowed to send money through Mass Pay
I made a special WPP test account co it should work. I have enough balance in account.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to request for it to be enabled on your account.
For the live PayPal site, call Customer Service and they'll know what to do.
For the Sandbox site, log a ticket at https://www.paypal.com/mts/

Comment: Thanks. It's little strange that on test account that option is not enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal just made a REST version of Payouts available. [Here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts-overview/) is the Payouts Overview.

To get access:

- Go to your dashboard on [developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com).
- Go to *My account*.
- Click *Get Started* under *Payouts*.

When you make it through, you'll also have *Mass Payments capability*.